# Cannot satisfy C++ range requirements custom container

Tags: c++, iterator, range, std-span

I have been trying to write a custom container with its own iterator which can be used as a range and with `std::span`. I am new to ranges, so please be kind.

The following example fails to compile, because my container class cannot be converted to a std::span

```
#include<span>
#include<vector>
#include<cstdint>


template<class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T>>
class MyContainer
{
public:
    class ConstIterator
    {
    public:
        using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
        using value_type = T;
        using difference_type = size_t;
        using pointer = T* const;
        using reference = const T&;
        
        ConstIterator() = default;
        ConstIterator(const ConstIterator &other) = default;
        
        
        ConstIterator(pointer ptr)
            : m_ptr(ptr) 
        {}

        reference operator*() const
        {
            return *m_ptr;
        }
        pointer operator->()
        {
            return m_ptr;
        }
        // Prefix increment
        ConstIterator& operator++()
        {
            m_ptr++;
            return *this;
        }
        // Postfix increment
        ConstIterator operator++(int)
        {
            Iterator tmp = *this;
            ++(*this);
            return tmp;
        }
        // Prefix decrement
        ConstIterator& operator--()
        {
            m_ptr--;
            return *this;
        }
        // Postfix decrement
        ConstIterator operator--(int)
        {
            Iterator tmp = *this;
            --(*this);
            return tmp;
        }
        ConstIterator& operator+=(const difference_type offset) noexcept
        {
            m_ptr += offset;
            return *this;
        }

        ConstIterator operator+(const difference_type offset) const noexcept
        {
            ConstIterator tmp = *this;
            tmp += offset;
            return tmp;
        }

        ConstIterator& operator-=(const difference_type offset) noexcept
        {
            return *this += -offset;
        }

        ConstIterator operator-(const difference_type offset) const noexcept
        {
            ConstIterator tmp = *this;
            tmp -= offset; 
            return tmp;
        }

        difference_type operator-(const ConstIterator& right) const noexcept
        {
            compatible(right);
            return m_ptr - right.m_ptr;
        }

        reference operator[](const difference_type offset) const noexcept
        {
            return *(*this + offset);
        }
        bool operator==(const ConstIterator& right) const noexcept
        {
            return (*this == right);
        }
        bool operator!=(const ConstIterator& right) const noexcept
        {
            return !(*this == right);
        }

        bool operator<(const ConstIterator& right) const noexcept
        {
            compatible(right);
            return m_ptr < right.m_ptr;
        }

        bool operator>(const ConstIterator& right) const noexcept
        {
            return right < *this;
        }

        bool operator<=(const ConstIterator& right) const noexcept
        {
            return !(right < *this);
        }

        bool operator>=(const ConstIterator& right) const noexcept
        {
            return !(*this < right);
        }
    protected:
        T* m_ptr;
    };
    class Iterator : public ConstIterator
    {
    public:
        using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
        using value_type = T;
        using difference_type = size_t;
        using pointer = T*;
        using reference = T&;
        
        Iterator() = default;
        Iterator(const Iterator &other) = default;

        Iterator(pointer ptr)
            : ConstIterator(ptr)
        {}

        reference operator*() const
        {
            return *ConstIterator::m_ptr;
        }
        pointer operator->()
        {
            return ConstIterator::m_ptr;
        }
        // Prefix increment
        Iterator& operator++()
        {
            ConstIterator::m_ptr++;
            return *this;
        }
        // Postfix increment
        Iterator operator++(int)
        {
            Iterator tmp = *this;
            ++(*this);
            return tmp;
        }
        // Prefix decrement
        Iterator& operator--()
        {
            ConstIterator::m_ptr--;
            return *this;
        }
        // Postfix decrement
        Iterator operator--(int)
        {
            Iterator tmp = *this;
            --(*this);
            return tmp;
        }
        Iterator& operator+=(const difference_type offset) noexcept
        {
            ConstIterator::_Verify_offset(offset);
            ConstIterator::m_ptr += offset;
            return *this;
        }

        Iterator operator+(const difference_type offset) const noexcept
        {
            Iterator tmp = *this;
            tmp += offset;
            return tmp;
        }

        Iterator& operator-=(const difference_type offset) noexcept
        {
            return *this += -offset;
        }

        Iterator operator-(const difference_type offset) const noexcept
        {
            Iterator tmp = *this;
            tmp -= offset;
            return tmp;
        }

        difference_type operator-(const ConstIterator& right) const noexcept
        {
            compatible(right);
            return ConstIterator::m_ptr - right.m_ptr;
        }

        reference operator[](const difference_type offset) const noexcept
        {
            return *(*this + offset);
        }
    };
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using allocator_type = Allocator;
    using pointer = typename std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::pointer;
    using const_pointer = typename std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::const_pointer;
    using reference = value_type &;
    using const_reference = const value_type &;
    using size_type = typename std::vector<T>::size_type;
    using difference_type = typename std::vector<T>::difference_type;
    using iterator = Iterator;
    using const_iterator = ConstIterator;
    using reverse_iterator = typename std::reverse_iterator<iterator>;
    using const_reverse_iterator = typename std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator>;

    MyContainer()
    {
        m_data.resize(10);
    }
    iterator begin()
    {
        return iterator(&m_data[0]);
    }
    iterator end()
    {
        return iterator(&m_data[0]+m_data.size());
    }
    const_iterator begin() const
    {
        return const_iterator(&m_data[0]);
    }
    const_iterator end() const
    {
        return const_iterator(&m_data[0]+m_data.size());
    }
   /*
    //These versions of begin() and end() work
    T* begin()
    {
        return &m_data[0];
    }
    T* end()
    {
        return &m_data[0]+m_data.size();
    }
    T* const begin() const
    {
        return &m_data[0];
    }
    T* const end() const
    {
        return &m_data[0]+m_data.size();
    }*/
private:
    std::vector<value_type> m_data;
};

int getSum(std::span<int const>s)
{
    int result =0;
    for (int val : s)
        result += val;
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    MyContainer<int> data;
    int sum = getSum(data);
}
```

Sorry this is a long minimal example, but my understanding is that a custom iterator needs to provide all the appropriate functionality to work with `std::span`.

The compilation error I am getting from clang is

```
<source>:282:12: error: no matching function for call to 'getSum'
        int sum = getSum(data);
                  ^~~~~~
<source>:271:5: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'MyContainer<int>' to 'std::span<const int>' for 1st argument
int getSum(std::span<int const>s)
    ^
1 error generated.
```

Or from VS2019

```
<source>(282): error C2664: 'int getSum(std::span<const int,18446744073709551615>)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'MyContainer<int,std::allocator<int>>' to 'std::span<const int,18446744073709551615>'
<source>(282): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
<source>(271): note: see declaration of 'getSum'
```

Clang was initially giving me errors about not satisfying the requirements for all of the various range types, up to and including input and output ranges and it referred to _Begin. But when I stripped the code back to this example, the message got less detailed.

This led me to think I have a problem with my iterator. If instead of returning my custom iterator I just return a raw pointer, then the code compiles fine.

Is there a way I can work out why my code is not working? I am struggling to even find a proper guide to all this that is penetrable to someone new to ranges.

Comment: I like that the prefix increment performs a postfix increment.

Comment: At a glance: (1) Your `Iterator::difference_type` is unsigned, which means nonsense when `a < b` and we do `a - b`. (2) Your addition (and subtraction) operation is not symmetric for `difference_type`. (3) Some methods aren't const qualified even though they can and should be. (4) `iterator_category` should be `std::contiguous_iterator_tag` as a span requires... There's probably gonna be more that needs done after, but that's all I can see.

Comment: Sidenote: Are you sure you want `using pointer = T* const;`? It seems `using pointer = T const*;` would be more fitting

Answer (score 2):

For anyone doing again in the future, the way I debugged my iterator was to set up a set of static asserts to check at which point my iterator was failing the requirements.
Because the iterator types form a hierarchy where each iterator must also satisfy the requirements of the one further down the hierarchy (other than input and output which are on par), I started with

```
    using cType = sci::MyContainer<int>;
    using iType = cType::Iterator;
    static_assert(std::input_iterator<iType>, "failed input iterator");
    static_assert(std::output_iterator<iType, int>, "failed output iterator");
    static_assert(std::forward_iterator<iType>, "failed forward iterator");
    static_assert(std::input_iterator<iType>, "failed input iterator");
    static_assert(std::bidirectional_iterator<iType>, "failed bidirectional iterator");
    static_assert(std::random_access_iterator<iType>, "failed random access iterator");
    static_assert(std::contiguous_iterator<iType>, "failed contiguous iterator");
```

Then I started with the first error, fount the code for that concept and set up `static_assert`s for the sub-concepts. For example, when I got a "failed input iterator" error I set up the static asserts

```
    static_assert(std::weakly_incrementable<iType>, "Failed the weakly incrementable test");
    static_assert(std::movable<iType>, "Failed the moveable test");
    static_assert(std::default_initializable<iType>, "Failed the default initializable test");
```

This allowed me to find (as noted by @Unslander Monica) that I had an unsigned `difference_type` when it needed to be signed, I did not have operators for `Iterator operator+(const difference_type offset, const Iterator &iter)`, I needed a `element_type` and for my non-`const` iterator I needed a `const pointer operator->() const`.